# How to view all currently logged in users on Alpine Linux?

Tags: alpine-linux, who

How to view all currently logged in users on Alpine Linux? It doesn't have `who` by default `apk add who` doesn't find any packages. Is there another package for Alpine that contains `who`? Or does it use some other utility for the same purpose?

I tried to look at the docs but searches for "list users" and "logged in users" didn't seem to yield results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `who` program is part of the `coreutils` package.  You can use `apk add coreutils` to install it:

```
# which who
#

# apk add coreutils
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/3) Installing libacl (2.2.53-r0)
(2/3) Installing libattr (2.4.48-r0)
(3/3) Installing coreutils (8.31-r0)
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r8.trigger
OK: 7 MiB in 17 packages
#

# which who
/usr/bin/who
#
```

Comment: You can install that on Alpine. But it will probably not show any users as musl doesn't implement `utmp`. See here: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/GNU_core_utilities